# Why the literal "-9223372036854775808" (min 64 bit signed integer) is not accepted by kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, number-literal

I'm trying to write a fast json parser for JVM in kotlin.

And I found this issue, I'm not sure this is a bug or any good reason behind this.

```
val x: Long = -9223372036854775808L  // compile error
```

Comment: And `-9223372036854775807L` is accepted, interesting... Btw, it would be helpful if the exact message was provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is marked as a bug in kotlin [KT-17172](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17172).

as you can see the stdlib using the code as below:

```
public const val MIN_VALUE: Long = -9223372036854775807L - 1L
```

are you remember unary operator `-` in kotlin? if you divide the `MIN_VALUE` into special parts you may see it clearly. for example:

```
val x: Long = -(9223372036854775808L);
//              ^--- the value overflow since the MAX_VALUE is 9223372036854775807L
```